# Should you use return or else? Which of these is optimal?

Tags: c#

Which of these is more optimal? Does it matter which one you use?

```
If (condition is true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("bad data");
    return;
}

//mode code here
```

or

```
If (condition is true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("bad data"); 
}
else
{
    //mode code here
}
```

Comment: They are mutually exclusive... it is not an either/or situation. If there is another option, you use `else`, if there isn't, you don't. `return` is also situational. There might be a time when you need it, and there will be many times when you don't.

Comment: _"Does it matter which one you use?"_ Of course, the first returns immediately, the second not.

Comment: The first method would be preferable if you follow *Object Calisthetics*, where a maximum of 1 level of indentation is allowed in a method, and they discourage the use of the `else` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are functionally the same.  Neither is actually superior to the other in terms of behavior or performance.  The only real issue here is readability, and that will vary based on the specifics of the example and the programming team involved.  So in short, pick whatever you want.

Note that your example should probably be a bit more complete for these assertions to hold true.  It should really be comparing;

```
public static void returnMethod()
{
    if (true)
        MessageBox.Show("bad data");

    //restOfMethod
}
```

with:

```
public static void elseMethod()
{
    if (true)
        MessageBox.Show("bad data");
    else
    {
        //restOfMethod
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The two are functionally the same"_. No, if that's just an excerpt and there's something after the `if-else`(f.e. `throw new Exception();`, you would get a different result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter As I stated in my answer, I assumed that the OP unknowingly gave an incomplete code snippet, and so I provided one that more accurately expresses what I feel he meant to ask.  Using that example, your point is specifically not possible (the entire point is that there is nothing after the `else`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter As I stated, it's clear to me that my code is a representation of his intent.  If I have misinterpreted, he should say so and it would indeed invalidate my answer.  I decided to answer what I felt he intended to ask rather than a literal answer to his question that is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: @TimSchmelter And now the OP has edited his post to reflect that my interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you mean is something more like

```
If (condition is true) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("bad data"); 
    return; 
} 

...more code here...
```

vs

```
If (condition is true)    
{    
    MessageBox.Show("bad data");     
}    
else    
{    
    ...more code here...
}
```

No, there is no performance difference.

This would fall more to design preferences.  Some people are die-hard-never-use-returns-to-get-out-of-a-method while others like to keep their code simple and neat, and if using a return helps that, so much the better.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a few things.  Do you have additional code after the conditional which would no longer be applicable?  If so, then return would be more optimal as it would prevent the impending statements from running.

The other idea is how this is placed?  If this is in a method that has a return, you would use that.  Likewise, if it was not applicable to have the surrounding function would accept a return, you wouldnt want to use *return*.

Does that make some sense?

Comment: The point is that there is something in the method after the `if` in the first example, and in the second example all of that code would be placed in the `else`, so the code is skipped either way, and there is no additional computation in either case; they will both end up being a guaranteed jump.

Comment: i mean, after the end brackets.   We are given a snippet..... so after the closing else brace.  There COULD be stuff after that which would be executed....  If that isnt needed any longer and it makes sense to have it return, do so.  As it would prevent running of code to hit everything after the condition

Comment: It's implied that (all of) the remaining code would be placed in the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say never have an empty else {} statement, unless it's just a place holder and in that case do something like

```
    else
    {
        //Todo: Fill in logic to handle the else case, waiting for business to get back to me
    }
```

Personally I think returning inside an "if" is fine, but if there's nothing below that if, writing "return;" is a waste of a few hundred pixels. If it does exactly the same thing with few pixels and isn't any harder to understand, I'd always go for it.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario where if-else and return would do the same thing (some examples are provided in other answers), I think readability is what matters.

I think that for one 'if' it doesn't really matter if you write an 'else' or directly 'return'. 
It gets worse when some 'if-else' statements are nested. It can be quite unreadable with multiple 'return' inside a method too.

I'm not a fan about nesting if-else's, neither of placing multiple returns inside the same method. But if I have to choose, I prefer to have multiple 'return'.